# unable to "vite build" for svelte and its components: skeleton and tailwind

Tags: npm, tailwind-css, vite, svelte, skeleton

I have tried the same on different version of node (v18 and v20) but still end up with the same error. I am trying to "vite build" svelte and some of its components, namely @skeletonlabs/skeleton @skeletonlabs/tw-plugin. The repo can be accessed here [Bundle-Svelte-Skeleton](https://github.com/ofjustpy/Bundle-Svelte-Skeleton).

The error while running "npm run build" is:

```
x Build failed in 609ms
error during build:
ParseError: Unexpected token

- Did you forget to add lang="ts" to your script tag?
    at error (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/utils/error.js:56:16)
    at Parser.error (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.js:143:3)
    at Parser.acorn_error (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.js:130:8)
    at Object.read_script [as read] (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/read/script.js:50:10)
    at tag (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/state/tag.js:203:27)
    at new Parser (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.js:91:12)
    at parse (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/parse/index.js:268:17)
    at Module.compile (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@4.2.12/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/index.js:136:14)
    at compileSvelte (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.2_svelte@4.2.12_vite@5.1.5/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/src/utils/compile.js:147:22)
    at async Object.transform (file:///home/kabiraatmonallabs/Skeleton_MeltUI/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.2_svelte@4.2.12_vite@5.1.5/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/src/index.js:152:20)
```